# How to do a local mysql database replication on an online server

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have developed a local and an online system that enables a company that has many branches all over the world to add informations with an auto increment Id. So the first record will have one as Id and other informations like name email...

My aim is to enable the company to make registration by default online but if the Internet goes off, i would like the company to continue the registration offline and I would like my script to update the online database when the Internet comes back.

I am new to mysql replication so I did something like this for my table both online and offline

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ojm_peoples` (
  `id_ojm_peoples` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `password` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `is_updated` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ojm_peoples`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

The column **is_updated** is used here to put every new record at **No** when the page url contains localhost or 127.0.0.1 which means we are in local and we will have to update this later by bringing it to the server.

**Problem:**

With php I can detect which url whether the url is Localhost or 127.0.0.1 which can help me know whether we are on local or online  BUT if we are in local :

**QUESTION :**

How can I make the local database connect to the online database that is on another server and insert the information that has the attribute **is_updated=No**  ?

Comment: Fetch all records from local database; insert in online database and then clear the local database.

Comment: I'd suggest that instead of reinventing the wheel, you can make use of the MySql replication. Details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html). You may run into issues of managing the "latest updates" yourself if you want to make the replications yourself.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel That's what I am trying to do only that I wonder how to avoid conflict with the existing Id on the online server compare to the local server.

Comment: @TJ- Thanks but can i do this on a shared server ? Because I am on a Shared server so I do no have access to all server functionalities

Comment: @FerdineFaithfull you can avoid the conflict by looping through each record on localhost and inserting it in the online database. I assume/ suggest that online database has auto-increment of the unique id. Anyway you'll be looking up data from online database so there's no need for pinning down exact id in local database.